# Nested Sets через PDO

Tags: pdo, nested-sets, php

Доброго времени суток.
Знаете ли Вы какой-нибудь класс для работы с Nested Sets при помощи PDO ?

Очень хотелось бы, чтобы он был хорошо задокументирован. Например читание помощи к http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdo-ns/ и курение исходников ни на какие полезные мысли не сподвигло.

Думал PEAR поможет, но нет- DB_NestedSets использует mysql_* (которые в будущем будут убраны из PHP), а DB_NestedSets2 вообще присутствует только в виде ссылки.  
Да и поиск **php pdo nested sets example** в разных вариациях не дает ничего хорошего.

Comment: Вот пример на вскидку
[http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdo-ns/][1]
наверняка есть и еще


  [1]: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdo-ns/

Comment: @varz62, прочтите, пожалуйста, вопрос. Делаю Ваш ответ комментарием.

Comment: можно так https://github.com/blt04/doctrine2-nestedset попробовать... но это уже ОРМ, хотя так то да, и PDO и nested sets ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В результате курения исходников класса и массы свободного времени решил написать этот [пост](http://reinraus.ru/wordpress/php-rabota-s-nested-sets-cherez-pdo/) где постарался описать работу с Nested Sets через PDO при помощи класса http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdo-ns/